# How can I create a new data frame for each unique value in a column in R?

Tags: r

I am having some trouble trying to create a new data frame for each unique value in one of my columns in my data frame.

For example, I have a data frame set up similar to this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Fruit = c("Apples", "Apples", "Apples", "Oranges", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Bananas"),
                  No. = c(2,8,7,1,4,9,6))
```

How can I create a new dataframe for each unique value AND name the data frame after the unique value?

I know that I can use subset like this:

```
Apples <- subset(df1, df1$Fruit == "Apples")
Oranges <- subset(df1, df1$Fruit == "Oranges")
Bananas <- subset(df1, df1$Fruit == "Bananas")
```

But I have over 100 unique values in my column in my data frame.

Comment: `list2env(split(df1, df1$Fruit), .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: yes that will work nicely, thank you so much. I did an extensive search for my answer but couldn't locate the similar question mentioned above.